# rxjava - How to groupBy process by type and merge back?

Tags: functional-programming

Assuming I have a List of fruits objects of type Apple and Orange, what is the recommended functional/reactive pattern, using rxjava, to group the fruits by fruit type, perform "fruit specific" operations (could be done in parallel) and subscribe to the result.

My line of thinking goes along the line of:

```
List<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<>();
fruits.add(new Apple());
fruits.add(new Orange());

Observable<GroupedObservable<Fruit>> fruitGroup = Observable.from(fruits)
    .groupBy(fruit -> fruit.getClass())
    .cache();

Observable<Boolean> appleActions = fruitGroup
    .filter(fruitG -> fruitG.getKey().equals(Apple.class))
    .flatMap(fruitG -> {
        return flatMap(apple -> Observable.just(apple.peel()))
    })

Observable<Boolean> orangeActions = fruitGroup
    .filter(fruitG -> fruitG.getKey().equals(Orange.class))
    .flatMap(fruitG -> {
        return flatMap(orange -> Observable.just(orange.cutInHalf()))
    })

appleActions.concatWith(orangeActions).subscribe();
```

Is the above the recommended approach to split a collection by type (or a criteria, for that matter), process each type individually using type specific action(s) and join/subscribe once every elements have been processed? What do you recommend? Thanks.